# BindingExpression path error when applying BindableSelection (WinRTXAMLToolkit)

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to two ListViews in snyc (one being display when the app is in Fullscreen, one for snapped view). This is mainly done so I can work with the SelectionChanged-Event of the main ListView. Unfortunately, using WinRTXamlFramworks BindableSelection just results in an Error:

> Error: BindingExpression path error: 'FilterListView' property not
>   found on
>   'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[[Filter.FilterType,
>   Filter, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]],
>   System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. BindingExpression:
>   Path='FilterListView'
>   DataItem='System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[[Filter.FilterType,
>   Filter, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]],
>   System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'; target element is
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView' (Name='FilterListViewSnapped');
>   target property is 'BindableSelection' (type 'Object')

From the error I assume this has something to do with the ItemSouce-Binding, but  I'm not sure on how to fix that. Any ideas?

Here's my XAML:

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" 
    Name="FilterListView" 
    SelectionMode="Single" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
    SelectionChanged="FilterListView_SelectionChanged">

<ListView x:Name="FilterListViewSnapped"
    Grid.Row="3" 
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
    SelectionMode="Single" 
    IsSwipeEnabled="false" 
    XamlToolkit:ListViewExtensions.BindableSelection="{Binding FilterListView, Mode=TwoWay}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

"{Binding FilterListView, Mode=TwoWay}" binds to the property "FilterListView" of FilterListViewSnapped's DataContext. IIRC for a ListView DataContext is generally the same as the ItemsSource.

If you want to bind to the ListView named "FilterListView", use this:
"{Binding ElementName=FilterListView, Mode=TwoWay}".

Comment: this does not work using WinRTXamlToolKits "BindableSelection".

Comment: Right, but that's what the error message wants to tell you. If you want to have two listviews to use the same bindableselection, then you need to attach the property to both listviews and bind it to a collection. This collection needs to be provided by your code. If binding to this collection doesn't work, examine (or post) the error messages.